# Scramble a Megaminx!

Tags: code-golf, string, rubiks-cube

## Scramble a Megaminx!

A megaminx is a dodecahedral version of the familiar Rubik's cube. Since 2008, the World Cube Association uses [Stefan Pochmann's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40544/stefan-pochmann) [megaminx scrambler](https://www.stefan-pochmann.info/spocc/other_stuff/tools/scramble_megaminx/). The scrambles look like this:

```
R-- D++ R++ D-- R++ D-- R++ D++ R-- D-- U'
R++ D-- R++ D-- R-- D++ R-- D-- R-- D-- U'
R++ D++ R-- D++ R++ D++ R++ D++ R-- D++ U 
R-- D-- R++ D++ R++ D++ R-- D++ R++ D++ U 
R-- D++ R++ D-- R++ D-- R++ D++ R++ D++ U 
R++ D++ R++ D++ R-- D-- R-- D-- R-- D-- U'
R-- D++ R-- D++ R++ D++ R++ D++ R++ D++ U
```

A scramble has seven lines. Each line has 10 R and D moves, starting with R and alternating R and D moves. Following each letter is randomly chosen direction `++` or `--` with equal probability. At the end of the line is randomly chosen with equal probability `U` (trailing space form `U`  allowed) or `U'`. A trailing newline at the end of the output is permitted.

Your code must take no input and must produce a random scramble.

Comment: Woops.. I accidently deleted my comment. So I'll just ask it again.. Are we allowed to output in lowercase (`rdu`) instead of uppercase?

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>73</s></sup> 71 bytes

*Saved two bytes thanks to @vrintle (one directly and another with further golfing)*

```ruby
77.times{|i|$><<(~i%11>0?:RD[i%2]+'+-'[rand 2]*2+' ':?U+?'*rand(2)+$/)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39xcryQzN7W4uiazRsXOxkajLlPV0NDOwN4qyCU6U9UoVltdW1c9uigxL0XBKFbLSFtdQd3KPlTbXl0LJKZhpKmtoq9Z@/8/AA)

`$/` is the input record separator, which is a newline by default.

---

In Ruby 2.7 (newer than the version on TIO), we get 70 bytes using numbered block parameters:

```ruby
77.times{$><<(~_1%11>0?:RD[_1%2]+'+-'[rand 2]*2+' ':?U+?'*rand(2)+$/)}
```

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31yvJDM3tbja0ADKqMmqUbGzsbEKconOUjWK1VbX1lWPLkrMS1EwitUy0lZXUK/lKigtKVYPVde2V9cCyWgYadb@/w8A "Ruby – Try It Online") or [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39xcryQzN7W4uiazRsXOxkajLlPV0NDOwN4qyCU6U9UoVltdW1c9uigxL0XBKFbLSFtdQd3KPlTbXl0LJKZhpKmtxKWkWfv/PwA "Ruby – Try It Online"), whichever you can golf further ;-)

Comment: @vrintle Very nice. Saved another byte with a predefined variable :)

Comment: btw, why are you preventing Ruby 2.7?

Comment: @vrintle Force of habit mainly. I do like numbered parameters but it's mildly annoying having to modify TIO's copy-paste template.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
from random import*
for C in[choice]*7:print' '.join(c+C('+-')*2for c in'RD'*5),'U'+C("' ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXlFyk4K2TmRSdn5Gcmp8ZqmVsVFGXmlagrqOtl5WfmaSRrO2uoa@uqa2oZgdQmA9WqB7moa5lq6qiHqgMlldQVlDT//wcA)

Alternatively:

```python
from random import*
C=choice
exec'print" ".join(c+C("+-")*2for c in"RD"*5),"U"+C("\' ");'*7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocTnbJmfkZyancqVWpCarFxRl5pUoKSjpZeVn5mkkaztrKGnrKmlqGaXlFykkK2TmKQW5KGmZauoohSqBJGPUFZQ0rdW1zP//BwA)

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes**

```python
from random import*
C=choice
for c in('RD'*5+'U')*7:print c+[C("+-")*2,C("' ")+"\n"][c>"T"],
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocTnbJmfkZyancqXlFykkK2TmaagHuahrmWqrh6praplbFRRl5pUoJGtHO2soaesqaWoZ6QBZ6gpKmtpKMXlKsdHJdkohSrE6//8DAA)

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes**

```python
from random import*
for C in[choice]*7:
 for c in'RD'*5:print c+C('+-')*2,
 print'U'+C("' ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXlFyk4K2TmRSdn5Gcmp8ZqmVtxKYAEk4GC6kEu6lqmVgVFmXklCsnazhrq2rrqmlpGOlwKYDH1UHWgoJK6gpLm//8A)

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXlFyk4K2TmRSdn5Gcmp8ZqmVsVFGXmlWhoaSRrO2uoa@uqa2oZgVQlA1WpB7moa5lq6qiHqgMlldQVlDQ1//8HAA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") with Python 3.8

Comment: The two for loops answer is surprisingly readable for being golved.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 68 bytes

```perl
say+(map{map$_.("++ ","-- ")[rand 2],R,D}0..4),U,"'"x rand 2for 0..6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbIzexoBqIVeL1NJS0tRWUdJR0dRWUNKOLEvNSFIxidYJ0XGoN9PRMNHVCdZTUlSoUIBJp@UUKQGGz////5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0AAA)

Comment: Nice one! With a couple of minor tweaks you can save a few bytes too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbIzexQCVer7BcQ1tbQVdXM7ooMS9FwShWT0VJRyNIx0WzwlRTJ1RHSV2pQgEilZZfpGCgp2f2//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>135</s> <s>132</s> <s>124</s> <s>123</s> 119 bytes

- -12 thanks to ceilingcat
- -1 by rearranging the inner `for` terms

For each line, I start with `R++` and then flip `R`=>`D` and `++`=>`--` (half the time). This continues ten times and concludes with either `U` or `U'`. Instead of doing string operations, I use XOR for all the manipulations and print the integer as a reinterpreted string.

```c
f(j){long i,k=7;for(srand(time(0));k--;puts(rand()%2?"U'":"U"))for(j=10,i=' ++R';j--;printf(&i))i^=22+rand()%2*394752;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvfCoIwFIDxe59iDMpz0oGtQmqM3iHwNpDZ5PhnhlpdiK/eyqDbj99nRGmM9xYqnJrOlYziWqfKdj0Mfe4KGKm9QYKoaiHU/TEO8Mu4kmeehfzEM4648Epvk5h0yKLoEqpq0T250cKaEOmqpYz@52Z33KcHqWb/BazNycGzowLZFDBmAVUw@7exTV4OXrw@)

Comment: wdym randomly flipping between `++` and `--`? Do you mean there is a 50% chance that the sign will change? Then that should be valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.6], <strike>144</strike> <strike>121</strike> <strike>120</strike> 111 bytes

*Huge reduction thanks to Sisyphus, and qwr*

```python
from random import*
d=choice
for r in range(35):print(end=f"R{d('-+')*2} D{d('-+')*2} "+r%5//4*f"U{d(' !')}\n")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXYJmfkZyancqXlFykUKWTmgRSkp2oYm2paFRRl5pVopOal2KYpBVWnaKjraqtrahnVKrggc5S0i1RN9fVNtNKUQkHiCorqmrUxeUqa//8DAA)

Each time through the loop prints one pair of entries, one `R` and one `D`.  The `r%5//4*f*` control takes care of conditionally printing the `U` entry and the end of line.

Comment: [114 bytes using `random.choice` over string seq](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXYJmfkZyancqXlFykUKWTmgRSkp2oYm2paFRRl5pVopOal2KYpBVWnaKjraqtrahnVKrggc5S0i1RN9fVNtDTUQ9W1UzSUFNSVNLXVY/LUNTX//wcA). Could be lower if I weren't too lazy to figure out how to encode the `'` in the f-string.

Comment: [111 bytes if we cheat and use a symbol like `i` instead of `'`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXYJmfkZyancqXlFykUKWTmgRSkp2oYm2paFRRl5pVopOal2KYpBVWnaKjraqtrahnVKrggc5S0i1RN9fVNtNKUQkHiCpnqmrUxeUqa//8DAA). The i notation or using the "prime symbol" is valid in terms of scrambles but no one does it.

Comment: The 111 version works w/ the `!` symbol so I left that, for consistency with the problem description.

Comment: I use `i` because it was formerly common move notation and `!` isn't. But the difference isn't big.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 bytes

```r
s=sample;for(i in 1:7)cat(paste0(c("R","D"),s(c("++","--"),10,T)),s(c("U","U'"),1),"
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9i2ODG3ICfVOi2/SCNTITNPwdDKXDM5sUSjILG4JNVAI1lDKUhJR8lFSVOnGMTR1gbydHWBXEMDnRBNqGgoUDBUHSSoqaPEpaT5/z8A)

[R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s `paste0` function (to paste text strings together without separator) is conveniently vectorized, so we can exploit [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s element recycling when the two arguments are different lengths: in this case, the 2-element vector `R,D` is automatically recycled 5 times when `paste0`-ed  with the 10-element vector created by `sample`-ing `++,--` ten times.  The `T` argument to `sample` indicates that sampling with replacement is `T`rue (needed to take 10 samples from 2-elements).

Comment: nice use of recycling.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 40 bytes

```
7*$(5*$(R-- D-- )U'¶
/--/_?&K`++
%?&`'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tcS0XDFIiDdHUVXIBYM1T90DYufV1d/Xh7Ne8EbW0uVXu1BHWu//8B) Explanation:

```
7*$(5*$(R-- D-- )U'¶
```

Insert 7 lines consisting of `R-- D--`  repeated 5 times followed by `U'`.

```
/--/_?&K`++
```

Match each `--` and then randomly replace each one with `++`.

```
%?&`'
```

On each line, randomly delete `'`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 56 bytes

```apl
''' '[?7/2],⍨'U',⍨7 10⍴,/⍉2 70⍴(2/¨'+-')[?70/2],⍨70⍴'RD'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@6urqCerS9ub5RrM6j3hXqoeogylzB0OBR7xYd/Ue9nUYK5iC2hpH@oRXq2rrqmkDVBlDlYBn1IBd1kGH/0wA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```javascript
f=k=>k>69?'':'RD'[k&1]+((r=Math.random()*4)&1?'++ ':'-- ')+(k%10>8?r&2?`U'
`:`U
`:'')+f(-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbb1i7bzszSXl3dSj3IRT06W80wVltDo8jWN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dDU8tEU83QXl1bWwGoTFdXQV1TWyNb1dDAzsK@SM3IPiFUnSvBKiEUSKgDpdI0dOuyNf8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaWhq/gcA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

A non-recursive approach.

```javascript
_=>`RDRDRDRDRDU
`.repeat(7).replace(/./g,c=>c+[['++ ','-- ',"'"][Math.random()*2|2*(c>'R')]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i4hyAUGQ7kS9IpSC1ITSzTMNUGsnMTkVA19Pf10nWRbu2Tt6Gh1bW0FdR11XV0gqaSuFBvtm1iSoVeUmJeSn6uhqWVUY6SlkWynHqSuGRur@T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNQ1PzPwA)

Comment: Interesting - how does the `k` variable work?

Comment: @qwr It's undefined during the first iteration. So, `k&1` is `0` and `k%10` is `NaN` (falsy). Then `-~k` sets it to `1` and the weirdness ends here.

Comment: I love and hate the idea of having undefined variables used

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>113</s> <s>97</s> 126 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17360/qwr)!!!
Added 29 bytes to fix an error kindly pointed out by [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17360/qwr).

```python
from random import*
f=lambda n=5,r=choice:n and f"R{r('-+')*2} D{r('-+')*2} "+f(n-1)or'U'+r(" '")
for i in range(7):print(f())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwEADvfcWSS3Ybe1ARoZCbLxB8QGy7NmA2YclFxLfHevM0DAxMedU1y7E11pxAg8wbYipZa9@xf4Z0nwOIP@3UT2uO0zIKbBWwub4V7eAs9YcPXP7FOEYZ9pTV3qxTNGANdZwVIkT5XR4LnmksGqUiI1FrXw)

Comment: [112 bytes using `random.random` and `r()>.5`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXZ5iTmJqUkKuTZmukU2UJkrfIUgLRCmlJQtbqutnp0kYamnZ5prJZRrYILhoiSdppGnq6hZn6Reqi6tpKCuhJM9n9afpFCpkJmHsjS9FQNQ2NNq4KizLwSjTQNTc3/AA)

Comment: Are you sure your TIO is correct? Don't you need to include the footer as bytes?

Comment: anyway, [97 bytes using `random.choice`](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwEADvvmLJJdnGHlRQKOTmCwQfENuuDZjdsORSxLfHevM0DAxMWesifGqNVDJo5GlDykW0djsKr5gfUwQO572GcZE0zgPDVgGZ21ud7b3F7viB678YT477A4rau/XqDFiDjUQhQeLf5Tm7Cw5FE1dHDrF9AQ)

Comment: @qwr Nice one - thanks! No, you don't include the header or footer. Just the solution to the challenge.

Comment: but your function needs to produce 7 lines of output

Comment: @qwr Oops, missed that - thanks! :-)

Comment: Use `exec("print(f());"*7)` to save some bytes. Although there is probably a better way to loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

**Credit goes to Kevin Cruijssen for coming up with this way shorter program!**

```
„RDÞε„+-Ωº«}Tôε„U'ηΩª}7£»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8IJfD885tBTK0dc@tPLTr0OrakMNbwAKh6ue2A4VW1ZofWnxo9///AA)

## How this?

```
„RDÞ                                        # Push RDRDRDRDRDRDRDRDRDRD... as a list
    ε      }                                # For every R or D:
     „+-Ω                                   #   Pick random from + and -
         º                                  #   Double the sign
          «                                 #   And join it to the R or D
            Tô                              # Split the list into pieces of 10 elements
              ε      }                      # For each item in the list:
               „U'ηΩ                        #   Choose a random choice between U' & U
                    ª                       #   Append it to the list
                      7£»                   # Join the first 7 lists with linefeeds
                                            # Print the result at the end (implicitly)!
```

---

My old program:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 36 bytes

```
8G„RD5×S"++ -- "3ôTи2ô€ΩøJ…U'U2ôΩªJ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9vc2FiaWX//zhH4oCeUkQ1w5dTIisrIC0tICIzw7RU0Lgyw7TigqzOqcO4SuKAplUnVTLDtM6pwqpKLP//)

## How that?

```
8G                                          # Repeat 7 times the full code
  „RD5×                                     # Push "RDRDRDRDRD"
        "++ -- "3ô                          # Push the list/array ["++ ", "-- "]
                  Tи2ô                      # Repeat the list 10 times
                      €Ω                    # Pick a random item from each list
       S                øJ        J         # Zip the random items with "RDRDRDRDRD"
                                            # e.g => "R++ D-- R++ D-- R++ D-- R++ D-- R++ D-- "
                          …U'U2ôΩ           # Pick random between "U'" and "U"
                                 ª          # Append the result to the last result
                                  ,         # Print it with a linefeed
```

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8IJfD885tBTK0dc@tPLTr0OrakMNbwAKh6ue2A4VW1ZofWnxo9///AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｅ⁷⪫⮌Ｅ¹¹⎇λ⁺§RDλ×²‽+-…U'⊕‽²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvBCoMwEATQX1ly6YbGg1566KnYi0JBpP2AkCwYSDYSrdSvT1PpHGfemEknE7XPeUiOV3zoGS8K@ugYR9ooLXR0da3gSYl12tErGPx7wdvasaUPivEuFHhZhAu0YKNg1GxjQHGuhJRlaHfjqZ3ijOJ1KrhjkygQr2Txbxt5RIGA3@eac642/wU) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ⁷                          Literal `7`
Ｅ                           Map over implicit range
     ¹¹                     Literal `11`
    Ｅ                       Map over implicit range
           RD               Literal string `RD`
          §  λ              Indexed by inner index
         ⁺                  Concatenated with
                 +-         Literal string `+-`
                ‽           Random character
              ×²            Duplicated
       ⎇λ                   Except for the first entry use
                    U'      Literal string `U'`
                   …        Truncated to length
                       ‽²   Random integer less than 2
                      ⊕     Incremented
   ⮌                        Reversed (so `U` is now last)
  ⪫                         Joined with spaces
                            Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/iki/Code-page)

```
7µ5,6ṁ11ż2Xx¤€$+0¦2ị“+-' RDU”KFṖ)Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//N8K1NSw24bmBMTHFvDJYeMKk4oKsJCswwqYy4buL4oCcKy0nIFJEVeKAnUtG4bmWKVn//w)**

#### How?

```
7µ5,6ṁ11ż2Xx¤€$+0¦2ị“+-' RDU”KFṖ)Y - Link: no argments
7                                  - seven
 µ                              )  - for each (v in [1..7]):
  5,6                              -   [5,6]
     ṁ11                           -   mould like 11 -> [5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5]
              $                    -   last two links as a monad:
             €                     -     for each:
            ¤                      -       nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
         2                         -         two
          X                        -         random integer (from [1,2])
           x                       -         repeat (two) times -> [1,1] or [2,2]
        ż                          -     zip together -> [[5,[2,2]],[6,[1,1],...]
                0¦                 -   apply to index 0 (rightmost):
               +  2                -     add two (e.g. [5,[1,1]] -> [7,[3,3]])
                    “+-' RDU”      -   "+-' RDU"
                   ị               -   index into (i.e. 1 -> '+' ... 7 -> 'U')
                             K     -   join with space characters
                              F    -   flatten
                               Ṗ   -   pop (remove the repeated space or quote from the right)
                                 Y - join with newline characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
V7jd+m+@"RD"d*2O"+-"T+\UO" '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8w8K0U7V9tBKchFKUXLyF9JW1cpRDsm1F9JQf3/fwA)

```
V7jd+m+@"RD"d*2O"+-"T+\UO" '   
V7                             Perform the following 7 times:
     m              T          Map d over 0-9:
               O"+-"             Choose + or - at random
             *2                  Double it
       @"RD"d                    Choose R for even d, D for odd
      +                          Concatenate the previous two results
                        O" '   Choose space or ' at random
                     +\U       Append to "U"
    +                          Append the previous result to the list of moves
  jd                           Join the list on spaces, implicit print with newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
7{ûRD5*môû+-w∞ ûU'1w╛╡n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9tYXRoZ29sZv//N3vDu1JENSptw7TDuystd@KIniDDu1UnMXfilZvilaFu//8)

Could be 22 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) if we're allowed to output in lowercase instead of uppercase, by changing the `ûRD` to `╢x` (and `U'` to `u'`): [try it online.](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9tYXRoZ29sZv//N3vilaJ4NSptw7TDuystd@KIniDDu3UnMXfilZvilaFu//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
7{                       # Loop 7 times:
  ûRD                    #  Push string "RD"
     5*                  #  Repeat it 5 times: "RDRDRDRDRD"
       m                 #  Map over each character,
        ô                #  using the following six character as inner code-block:
         û+-             #   Push string "+-"
            w            #   Pop and push a random character from this string
             ∞           #   Double it
                         #   Push a space character " "
               ûU'      '#  Push string "U'"
                  1w     #  Push a random integer in the range [0,1]
                    ╛    #  If this integer is truthy (thus 1):
                     ╡   #   Discard the right character of the string
                      n  #  Push a newline character "\n"
                         # (after the loop, the entire stack joined together is output
                         #  implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 40 bytes

```
7"RD""35"≈*⌠"+-"Jτ+R⌡M╡⌠2"UU'"╡J@+' j⌡Mi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/99cKchFScnYVOlRZ4fWo54FStq6Sl7nW7SDHvUs9H00dSFQyEgpNFRdCcj2ctBWV8gCSWT@/w8A)

```
 "RD"                                    # Push RD,
     "35"≈*                              # and repeat it 35 times.
           ⌠        ⌡M                   # For each turn,
           ⌠"+-"J   ⌡M                   # pick either + or -,
           ⌠     τ  ⌡M                   # double it,
           ⌠      +R⌡M                   # and add it to the end of each turn.
7                     ╡                  # Split the list into 7 sublists (of length 10).
                       ⌠             ⌡M  # For each sublist,
                       ⌠2"UU'"╡J     ⌡M  # pick either U or U',
                       ⌠        @+   ⌡M  # add it to the end of each turn,
                       ⌠          ' j⌡M  # and join with spaces.
                                       i # Push each sublist to the stack.
                                         # Implicitly output the stack joined with newlines.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 86 bytes

A golfed version of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216302/83605), which he didn't approved. Perhaps, because his answer is in Python 2.

```python
from random import*
for C in[choice]*7:print(*(c+C('+-')*2for c in'RD'*5),'U'+C("' "))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocaXlFyk4K2TmRSdn5Gcmp8ZqmVsVFGXmlWhoaSRrO2uoa@uqa2oZgVQlA1WpB7moa5lq6qiHqgMlldQVlDQ1//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>78</s>, 75 bytes

Saved **3 bytes** by modifying the jump in the third line and changing how the register was checked and decremented.

```
7_a*&"DR"d1.  >x"-"v
>x"'"oao&:&?!;^\"+">$:o$:oo$" "od1&1-:&a%?.~~"U"o
.>51
```

New link:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zw@UUtNySVIKcVQT0HBrkJJV6mMC0ipK@Un5qtZqdkrWsfFKGkr2alY5QNRvoqSglJ@iqGaoa6VWqKqvV5dnVKoUj6Xnp2p4f//AA)

Old link: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zw@UUtNySVIKcVQT0HBrkJJV6mMC0ipK@Un5qtZqdkrWsfFKGkr2akZ6qqpWOUDUb6KkoJSfoohUDZR1V6vrk4pVCmfS8HO1FDv/38A)

This code also runs in [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish) (Starfish) because [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish) is a super set of [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish).

*><>: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/988PlFLTcklSCnFUE9Bwa5CSVepjAtIqSvlJ@arWanZK1rHxShpK9mpWOUDUb6KkoJSfoqhmqGulVqiqr1eXZ1SqFI@l56dqeH//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 25 bytes

```
₀(‛RD5*ƛ‛+-℅d+;\U‛U'"℅JṄ,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%28%E2%80%9BRD5*%C6%9B%E2%80%9B%2B-%E2%84%85d%2B%3B%5CU%E2%80%9BU%27%22%E2%84%85J%E1%B9%84%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explanation

```
₀(‛RD5*ƛ‛+-℅d+;\U‛U'"℅JṄ,
 (                         For n
₀                          in range(10):
  ‛RD                        Push "RD"
     5*                      Repeat 5 times
       ƛ      ;              Map:
        ‛+-                    Push "+-"
           ℅                   Choose random
            d                  Double
             +                 Concatenate top two
               \U            Push "U"
                 ‛U'         Push "U'"
                    "        Join top two into a pair
                     ℅       Choose random
                      J      Join top two
                       Ṅ     Join with spaces
                        ,    Print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 129 bytes

```
import random
randomize()
for _ in 0..6:
 var l=["U","U'"].sample
 for i in 0..9:l="RD"[i mod 2]&["++","--"].sample&" "&l
 echo l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEoSgxLyU/lwtCZValamhypeUXKcQrZOYpGOjpmVlxKZQlFink2EYrhSrpKIWqK8XqFSfmFuSkcimAFGZCFVpa5dgqBbkoRWcq5OanKBjFqkUraWsDdejqwnWoKSkoqeVwKaQmZ@Qr5Pz/DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
⁵µ⁾RDẋ5;⁾+-XḤ¤$€“U“U'”X¤ṭ)G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49ZDWx817gtyebir29QayNLWjXi4Y8mhJSqPmtY8apgTCsLqjxrmRhxa8nDnWk33//8B)

### Explanation

```
⁵µ⁾RDẋ5;⁾+-XḤ¤$€“U“U'”X¤ṭ)G  Main niladic link
⁵                            10 [implicitly casted to [1..10]]
 µ                       )   Map:
  ⁾RD                          "RD"
     ẋ5                        Repeat 5 times
               €               Map
              $                (
       ;                         Join with
             ¤                   (
        ⁾+-                        "+-"
           X                       Choose random
            Ḥ                      Unhalve (double)
             ¤                   )
              $                )
                        ṭ      Append
                       ¤       (
                “U“U'”           ["U", "U'"]
                      X          Choose random
                       ¤       )
                          G  Format as a grid
```